# No Class Found: com.google.common.collect.Lists

Tags: renjin

I am attaching a screen shot of the problem that I am facing with Renjin Engine. Please see the image below. I'm not able to load the Renjin Engine[image]

The debug output is also attached in the picture. Can you please help me debug this?

Comment: actually the RCA of error is in **RenjineScriptEngineFactory.java** i.e source file in Renjin Library so how I should resolve that... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) to your project.

Answer (score 2):

@robby-cornelissen is right: you are missing Guava from your classpath. If you're not going to use a build tool like Maven, Gradle, or SBT, then you need to manually add Renjin's dependencies to your classpath or use the [standalone .jar](https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=renjin-release&g=org.renjin&a=renjin-script-engine&c=jar-with-dependencies&v=RELEASE)  from http://renjin.org/downloads.html which includes all of Renjin's dependencies bundled into a single JAR.