# Android Studio error (Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I installed Android Studio 8.2.0 first time and this error is repeatedly occurring whenever i create a new project.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists
```

My gradel deetails are below

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.lifelinetracker"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.lifelinetracker"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.22")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.0.0-jre")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.+")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

}
```

I've tried following this one but it's not working as expected.
[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784495/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-gradle-internal-impldep-com-googl)

Need your support to find out what I am missing.

I've tried following this one but it's not working as expected.
[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784495/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-gradle-internal-impldep-com-googl)

Need your support to find out what I am missing.